# Error while installing Ubuntu (X86-64 CPU expected)

Tags: boot, system-installation, kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

While installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox, I got error messages:

`This kernel requires X86-64 CPU,but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU`.

How do I download the appropriate kernel?

Comment: Download and use the 32-bit version because that's the only one your hardware supports.

Answer (score 1):

I am also quite new, but I think you need to download the 32-bit version (i386). You will find it here http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/

Hope this helps!